# How to setup ragnraok/android-image-filter in android studio

Tags: android, imagefilter

I am working on `imagefiltering` function , for that I came across [ragnraok/android-image-filter](https://github.com/ragnraok/android-image-filter)

It has details about setting up in Eclipse **NOT** AndroidStudio

How do I do it in AndroidStudio ?

Comment: Add this library as module to your project so you can easily access. or do with eclipse and export to it for android studio it will convert android studio compatible by exporting option.

Comment: Let me try the module option :)

Comment: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating-from-eclipse-projects